# How to Send HTTP Request include dash - Avoid Invalid URI Exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, paypal, uri

All,

I am trying to send to paypal a http get request to obtain my security token but I received this exception:

```
https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -s --insecure -d PARTNER= -d VENDOR= -d USER= -d PWD= -d TRXTYPE=S -d AMT=40 -d CREATESECURETOKEN=Y -d SECURETOKENID=12528208de1413abc3d60c86cb1
```

Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

This is caused by having a dash "-" in the URL (I verified it)
I tried both approaches:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl)
```

Both generate same exception. The exception comes probably from the URI parsing implementation in .net.

So how, can I sent the request?